# How to disable and enable client validation in Razor using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have disabled client side validation for a field in my razor file by disabling the data-val attribute. The field looks like below

```
  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CallNoteViewModel.CallNote_Memo, 3, 15, 
                      new { @class = "form-control", **@data_val = "false"** })
```

I want to enable/disable the validation on that field based on whether a checkbox is ticked or not. I have my JQuery code as below.

```
       $('#checkbox').click(function () {
            if ($('#checkbox').prop('checked')) 
            {
                $('#CallNoteViewModel_CallNote_Memo').data('val', 'true');
                console.log($('#CallNoteViewModel_CallNote_Memo').data('val'));
            } 
            else
            {
                $('#CallNoteViewModel_CallNote_Memo').data('val', 'false');
                console.log($('#CallNoteViewModel_CallNote_Memo').data('val'));
            }
        });
```

I tried setting the data-val attribute by using attr() function in jQuery, but even that is enabling the client side validation.

How can I enable the client side validation for the field in jQuery?

Comment: The validator is parsed when the page is first loaded. If you change a `data-val-*` attribute you have to remove and the re-parse the validator.

Comment: The better way to handle this is with custom validation attributes. [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) has a number of useful attributes such as `[RequiredIfTrue]` which may suit your needs

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I used Foolprood and it's the exact sort of thing I am looking for. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the FoolProof library as suggested Stephen Muecke. It works perfectly for my cases.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using unobtrusive form validation.

```
$(function() {
if($('#' + checkboxId).is(":checked"))
{
    var config = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
    config.ignore = ".disableValidation";
}
});
```

Use the above code to disable validations for fields of your choice. Just add the class ".disableValidation" to the fields for which you want to disable validations. Validation will be disabled for these fields in the form.

Comment: Validation will **not** be disabled just by adding the class dynamically. The `validator` is parsed when the page is first loaded. It will only ignore fields where the class name exists when the page is first loaded